# In a heap data structure, could you have a parent node of 100 and 2 child nodes of 100 and 0, would it have any practical purpose?

Tags: data-structures

Learning about data structures, and it says that the only qualification of a max heap is that the child is less than or equal to the parent node, if so, is the top of any use?

Comment: It would be the largest value in the heap; I could see that being useful.

Comment: BTW, data structures don't involve language tags.  Replace your language tag with "data-structures".  For example, you could implement a heap data structure in FORTRAN or assembly language (and you didn't include those languages).

Answer (score 0):

The root node of a heap is usually the highest or lowest priority in the heap. This is useful for finding the min or max of a heap.